# problem in layout of page in admin panel

Tags: layout

i have problem in this page in catalog --> Data Feed
[image]

that's after upgrade from 2.1.10 to 2.3.5 , so any idea for how can i solve with explanation for beginner please  .
this is page source ,
[image]

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't customized the module for this then it will be a permissions issue

You can use these commands :

sudo chmod -R 777 generated/ var/ pub/

sudo chown -R username:username .

It may also help you:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Magento-2-admin-css-and-js-not-loading-after-trying-to-change/td-p/129871